# How can I get the input hdfs path in a python hadoop streaming mapper

Tags: python, hadoop, streaming

I'm writing a Hadoop streaming mapper using Python. The mapper has two inputs from different hdfs path. How can I get the input path of each line that the mapper is processing?

Thanks.

Comment: In python mapper script, os.environ["map_input_file"] refers to input file name. Is this you are expecting?

Comment: @SandeepKumar thanks a lot, that's exactly what I want..